# Vue - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded callWithAsyncErrorHandling

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

`<button onClick="test">Test</button>`

Horrible error in Vue 3 that took hours to find:

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded callWithAsyncErrorHandling
callWithAsyncErrorHandling
callWithAsyncErrorHandling
callWithAsyncErrorHandling etc

[image]

@vue/cli 4.5.11

{
"dependencies": {
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.10.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/express": "^4.17.8",
"nodemon": "^2.0.4",
"ts-node": "^9.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.0.3",
"webpack": "^4.44.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Cause - simple syntax error:
`<button onClick="test">Test</button>`

SOLVED:
`<button @click="test">Test</button>`

Comment: They could have added good exception for this, it would be difficult to solve in large projects.. thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't reproduce it in CodePen, so was unable to raise an Issue on GitHub.